# XML Transform with Python

Tags: python, xml, transform

I have a XML file like this:

```
<recommendations>
    <para>
        <text>Text.</text>
    </para>
    <para>
        <text>Text2.</text>
    </para>
</recommendations>
```

I want to make a new recommendations tag with "Text" concatenate with "Text2" using python:
Text.Text2.

can someone help me?

I tried so far:

```py
xml_parsed = ET.parse(file)
xml_parsed_root = xml_parsed.getroot()
recommendations_root = item.findall(r'recommendations')
for para in recommendations_root:
    for text in para:
        recommendations = ET.Element('recomendations')
        recommendations_root[text].text = text.text.append(recommendations)
    xml_root.append(item)
```

My expected Output:

```xml
<recommendations> Text.Text2. </recommendations>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to make just a tag <recommendations> with all <text> tags inside.

Comment: How should the output look like? Please update the post. What did you try so far?

Comment: Output: <recommendations> Text.Text2. </recommendations>

Comment: I tried
xml_parsed = ET.parse(file)
xml_parsed_root = xml_parsed.getroot()
recommendations_root = item.findall(r'recommendations')
for para in recommendations_root:
    for text in para:
        recommendations = ET.Element('recomendations')
        recommendations_root[text].text = text.text.append(recommendations)
    xml_root.append(item)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, I introduce a function `get_text()` which iterates through the root of the input and collect all texts. The rest would be easy:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def get_text(r):
    buffer = ""
    for para in r:
        for text in para:
            buffer += text.text
    return buffer

doc = ET.parse("data.xml")
root = doc.getroot()

out = ET.Element("recommendations")
out.text = get_text(root)
print(ET.dump(out))
```

Output:

```
<recommendations>Text.Text2.</recommendations>
```

#### Update

Instead of writing `get_text()`, you can also use Xpath:

```
out = ET.Element("recommendations")
out.text = "".join(node.text for node in root.findall(".//text"))
print(ET.dump(out))
```

Comment: I think I'll need to use the get_text() 'cause I have more variables, that I don't write here... I just write my problem. but thanks I think it'll work, tomorrow I'll try that